# handling events when app goes into the background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

What I want is that my app should stop playing sound when it enters the background (when home button is pressed). I did this in appDelegate.m but it says `use of undeclared identifier 'soundID'`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)
}
```

I have imported my VC into the delegate and have also exposed the `soundID` as a property. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"something" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)url, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that functionality you should go to your app main plist file (probably named *`[your-app-name]-Info.plist`*) and there find a key:

```
Required background modes
```

and remove value

```
App plays audio
```

That should do the trick.

----------------**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myWavFile" ofType:@"wav" inDirectory:@"DirectoryName"];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[self.player play];
```

Where self player is:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```

You should also:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

And add this framework to your project.

Comment: Then audio shouldn't play in background mode! Please post your code how you play audio.

Comment: I am using short system sound to play the audio. I will edit my question.